# Is there any way to package Famous the way their demos do it?

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to integrate the Famous libraries into an existing web application and the usage of requireJS with separate Famous JS files is giving me headaches.  The existing web application does not use requireJS and it would be a big project to retrofit it to do so.

However, when I look at this demo:

http://demo.famo.us/tentacles/

A "famous.lib.js" file is included which encapsulates all the requireJS functionality into a single file.

How is this file generated? Does the Famous toolchain allow for creating this?  If so, what is the command used?

The generator-famous docs say: "A single command to prepare your project for production".  That may be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure of the syntax for that command.

Does anyone know?

Comment: How did you find the link to http://demo.famo.us/tentacles/ ? I'm a registered famo.us user but can't find link to such demos.

Comment: Via Google.  I knew of the demo's existence from http://codepen.io/befamous/.  All of the demos on Codepen are also present on the Famous website if you search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The single command is simply 'grunt'

Run 'grunt' in your application's directory and it will create a distribution folder called 'dist'

Inside 'dist' you will find everything compact and ready to go.